# Differential calculus by Piskunov - Chapter 4, Problem 50

Tags: calculus

I can't seem to solve this limit question correctly. It would nice, if someone could help with a neat solution.

$\begin{align}L &=\lim_{x\rightarrow{\pi/2}}{(\cos{x})^{(\pi/2-x)}}
\end{align}$

Here is my attempt to solve it.

This is an indeterminate form $0^0$.

Let $y = (\cos{x})^{(\pi/2-x)}$.

$\ln{y} = {(\pi/2-x)}\ln(\cos{x})$

$\begin{align}\lim_{x\rightarrow{\pi/2}}{\ln{y}}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow{\pi/2}}{(\pi/2-x)}\ln(\cos{x})\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow{\pi/2}}\frac{\ln{\cos{x}}}{\frac{1}{\pi/2-x}}
\end{align}$

This is an indeterminate of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. Let $f(x)=\ln{\cos{x}}$, $g(x)=\frac{1}{\pi/2-x}$. Assuming that $f$ and $g$ are continuous and differentiable, we can apply the L'Hospital's rule.

$f^{(1)}(x)=-\tan{x}$

$f^{(2)}(x)=-\sec^2{x}$

$f^{(3)}(x)=-2\sec^{2}{x}\tan{x}$

$g^{(1)}(x)=\frac{-1}{(\pi/2-x)^2}(-1)$

$g^{(2)}(x)=\frac{-2}{(\pi/2-x)^3}(-1)$

$g^{(3)}(x)=\frac{-6}{(\pi/2-x)^4}(-1)$

$\begin{align}\lim_{x\rightarrow{\pi/2}}{\ln{y}}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow{\pi/2}}\frac{\ln{\cos{x}}}{\frac{1}{\pi/2-x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow{\pi/2}}\frac{-\tan{x}}{\frac{-1}{(\pi/2-x)^2}(-1)}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow{\pi/2}}\frac{-\sec^2{x}}{\frac{-2}{(\pi/2-x)^3}(-1)}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow{\pi/2}}\frac{-2\sec^{2}{x}\tan{x}}{\frac{-6}{(\pi/2-x)^4}(-1)}
\end{align}$

I am not sure, if I am getting anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You have
$$\lim_{x\uparrow\pi/2} \cos(x)^{\pi/2 - x} = \lim_{x\downarrow 0}\sin(x)^x.$$
Then
$$\log(L) = \lim_{x\downarrow 0} {x\log(\sin(x))} = \lim_{x\downarrow 0} {\log(\sin(x))\over 1/x}= -\lim_{x\downarrow 0} {\cos(x)\over \sin(x)/x^2} = 0$$

Therefore $L = 1$.

Comment: Thanks, I had a hunch to try that substitution to simplify the expression, but wasn't sure.:)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use $\begin{align} L &=\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \ln y = \lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}{\frac{1}{\ln cos}} \end{align} $